# Options to protect Mobile Phone from over charging which is causing battery failure

Tags: power, resistors

We have a number of  Android mobile phones permanently on charge. After approximately 3 months some of the device batteries expand considerable, splitting the phone & failing. The phones are in a regulated 23 °C environment, so I believe temperature is not the main problem. I believe overcharging is the problem, possibly due to the phones being low cost entry models and the internal regulator circuit not being great. Note that the screens are on permanently at full brightness. My guess is that they are using about 300 mW. The charger which comes with the phone is rated to 500 mA.

I've considered powering the phones directly without a battery however Android has gotten smarter and appears to require signals from the battery circuit board. My current thinking is to balance the charge capacity of the charger itself to the power the phone is using, e.g. a 300 mW charger.

My questions:

Would this strategy of  trying to balance the charging current of the USB charger with the power use of the phone be effective at preventing over charging?

If so, could I simply limit the charge current by sticking a resistor on the positive. Would a single resistor do the job? and if so what value range? An online calculator gives me:

- Resistance   16.667 Ω
- Voltage  5V
- Current  300 mA
- Actual Power Rating  1.5 W
- Recommended Resistor Wattage 2 Watt Resistor

Comment: Phone "chargers" aren't strictly speaking chargers at all, they're constant voltage DC power supplies. The actual charging circuitry is integrated into the phone itself (maybe except some of the oldest pre li-ion devices from the 90's). A phone draws only as much current as it needs to operate and charge; you could even connect one to a 100A power supply with no ill effects as long as the voltage is correct.

Comment: I'm assuming the phone's charging regulator is not doing a very good job. Maybe designed for the scenario where charging happens ever day or so. Would limiting what the phone can draw from the charger to what it is consuming reduce the  overcharging problem?

Comment: @BobOx I think it is too complex a situation to discuss here. In theory, when you buy an Android phone from a manufacturer/distributor, you have a right to expect that the phone, battery system, and its charger are properly mated and well-designed. You've basically said, "No, they are not. So what now?" The obvious answer is to find another device and give these away or throw them out, with a lesson learned for next time. Trying to suss out where the problem lays is probably beyond the scope for you and/or the rest of us. And "quick, blind fixes" are a fools' choice. I wish it were otherwise.

Comment: @BobOx That said, I pretty much agree with your flow of logic. You've addressed details such as the ambient temperature. You've stated that you keep these devices attached to their chargers. And I think you've managed to provide good evidence that (1) the phones and their chargers and battery systems are not designed well, or (2) you've bought a 3rd party charger to replace the original equipment manufacturer's version and applied it to a situation where it fails to work properly. Your only simple option is to buy a quality power source that meets or exceeds the phone specs, I guess, and hope.

Comment: The strategy to use a charger that delivers just the right amount of power to balance the consumption is fated to failure. Eventually the phone will go into a low power consumption mode and the battery will fully charge. Modern phones use switched-mode chargers that will deliver to the battery the expected amount of current (in constant current phase) or voltage (in constant voltage phase) over a relatively wide range of input voltage. Therefore, using an external resistor will probably not be as effective as you may think.

Comment: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-charging-limit-your-android-device-avoid-excess-battery-wear-0176280/

Comment: By any chance, are the phone near a window where it could get sunlight? I had a similar case and was cause be direct sunlight regularly heating up the phone, ending with the battery inflating and splitting the phone.

Comment: A slightly left of field approach might be to use something simple like a timer switch to turn the phone chargers off on the mains side for a few hours every few hours so the cells get to cycle as they should do.

Comment: I did look at timer switches. There is a USB charger specific one on the market but was a bit pricey, but maybe not too bad if the next option is HMI panels. I'm trying to keep the price per unit down. I've just bought a USB power meter and I'm going to log the current draw of the phone. Based on the other comments I think my idea of de-rating the power supply is probably "half-arsed" but I might still give it a try anyway. The phones run out of power when plugged into a PC as I guess the PC is only allowing maybe 100ma to be drawn.

Comment: For the record the phones are Vodafone Smart E9s with a TLi019D7 battery. I think its an alcatel manufactured phone. Not all have had the battery problem yet,3 so far but I think its just a matter of time for the rest.

Answer (score 2):

> We have a number of Android mobile phones permanently on charge.
>   Note that the screens are on permanently at full brightness.

Phones are not intended for such high duty cycle operation. They will overheat. This will cause the battery to be damaged.

> Would this strategy of trying to balance the charging current of the USB charger with the power use of the phone be effective at preventing over charging?

No. In fact it would make it refuse external power at all. Working from battery alone due to the voltage drop.

Options:

1. **Buy the correct devices. Search for HMI panels with Android.**
2. Remove the battery and connect to the battery terminals directly.
   If the phone is picky, pull the management board from the battery and use those BMS battery pins to connect approximately a 4V source, simulating the battery. Success not guaranteed. Warranty most definitely void.
   *Do this on a discharged battery and don't puncture or short the pouch.*

Comment: Some good points, thanks. I don't think heat is the issue though as I've taken the backs off the phones and the labels off the batteries to expose the aluminium casing, applied a thermal paste and stuck it on 3mm aluminium plate, to act as a heat sink. I havent measured the temperature but I'm guessing, by touch, maybe a 27c. I did look at HMI panels and at the low end I could get them for around US$200 however as I needed 25 and I could get a phone for $35 the economics won out. My thinking at the time was that a consumer mobile phone tends to live a hard life so probably ok for the job.

Comment: I have had a go at removing the management board from the battery. I could not remove the management board without damaging it. I tried with a small dremel disk grinder to cut away the seamless aluminium casing but almost immediately shorted it and got a nasty whiff of something, so left it to boil away. Interestingly after a few hours I was still measuring a 3v on it. Of the 4 pins the 1st and 3rd are power. I found the phone will work without the 4th pin connected but its looking for a signal from the 2nd pin. If I could somehow emulate this I might be on a winner.

Comment: I'm trialing reducing the charger current. With the phone at 100% the phone is pulling .34 to .54 A from the charger. It cycles up/down for whatever reason, not a stable current. Rather than a current limiting circuit I've put 2m of  USB cable in between. I let the phone drain to 90% and plugged it in. The draw is now .22A according to the meter & the voltage drops from 5.1v to 4.6v. The battery % on the phone, if it can be relied upon, is charging at +3% per hr. I'm thinking that this less vigorous trickle charging regime can only benefit the battery life.

Comment: @BobOx You're lucky the shop didn't burn to ashes. Never puncture lithium pouches. The current limit isn't going to be a stable long term solution. Reconsider the HMI panels, or maybe you have to admit you've sold something that cannot be done for $35.

Comment: I'm hopeful as the battery, with the current limited to .22A, is now at room temperature. I was surprised that without limiting the current, even at full charge, the phone was still drawing the maximum current of the charger at times (0.5A). I guess with the screen @ max brightness the regulator does not cope very well.